# Match a string with a substring in Expect scripting

Tags: linux, scripting, string, expect

I have an output like this:

```
Node Name                     Status        IP Address
======================================================
bw2acn0                      ENABLED      x.x.x.x
bw2acn1                      ENABLED     x.x.x.x
bw2dvn0                      ENABLED     x.x.x.x
bw2dvn1                      ENABLED     x.x.x.x
bw2vm0                       ENABLED      x.x.x.x
bw2vm1                       ENABLED      x.x.x.x
```

and I want to create a loop to see if this output contains any of the name of the apps.

```
#!/opt/tools/unsupported/expect-5.39/bin/expect

set HOST [ lindex $argv 0 ]
set USER [ lindex $argv 1 ]
set PASSWORD [ lindex $argv 2 ]
set APP1 [ lindex $argv 3 ]
set APP2 [ lindex $argv 4 ]
set APP3 [ lindex $argv 5 ]
set APP4 [ lindex $argv 6 ]

spawn ssh -l $USER $HOST
expect_after eof {exit 0}
set timeout 120

expect "password:" { send "$PASSWORD\r" }

expect "~]#" { set buff $expect_out(buffer)
foreach i $APPS {
     if {[regexp {"${i}"} $buff]} {
    log_file ../report.txti
            send_log "Commit nodes on $i ------------------------------- Passed\n\n"
            puts "*********************paased"
    } else {
    log_file ../report.txt
            send_log "Commit nodes on $i ------------------------------ Failed\n\n"
            puts "******************failed"
        }

}
}
log_file
send "\r"

expect "~]#" { send "date\r" }
expect "~]#" { send "exit\r" }
```

but all I get is that it goes to failed although it should go to pass.

Comment: Where is `$APPS` coming from in this update? Do you need a named list provided by `array(n)` or just a list of strings as command line arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if { $buff match {*$APP$i*} } {
```

What is `match`? There's [nothing in the `expr` documentation](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/expr.htm) that uses that term. Also where is the `APP` variable coming from? You've got `APP1` and so forth, but not `APP`.

The [`string` command group](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm) can match a string with `string match`, and an [`array`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/array.htm) (what other languages call a hash or associative array) likely better groups the application (node?) names rather than trying to use a variable as a variable name:

```
set theapps(app1) foo
set theapps(app2) bar
set theapps(app3) zot

set buff "blah bar blah"

foreach {name value} [array get theapps] {
    if {[string match "*$value*" $buff]} {
        puts "ok - $name $value"
    } else {
        puts "not ok - $name $value"
    }
}
```

When run, this matches `bar` for `app2`:

```
$ tclsh choices
not ok - app3 zot
not ok - app1 foo
ok - app2 bar
$
```

A second option is to use a list of items to search for. This can be done by shifting the not-application names off the arguments, then looping over the remaining items:

```
proc shift {list} {
    set result ""
    upvar 1 $list ll
    set ll [lassign $ll result]
    return $result
}

set HOST [shift argv]
set USER [shift argv]
set PASSWORD [shift argv]

puts "leading args: >$HOST< >$USER< >$PASSWORD<"

set buff "blah bar blah"

foreach substr $argv {
    if {[string match "*$substr*" $buff]} {
        puts "match >$buff< on >$substr<"
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting APPs from outside as an input to this expect file.

Comment: I have edited my question.