# Problem with 'string match' and variable

Tags: expect

I've been searching for hours and trying multiple things. This is the expect code snippet which works.

```
         foreach line [split $expect_out(buffer) \r\n] {
            if {[string match {*word*} $line]} {
               send_user "$line\r\n"
               set acctnum [exec echo $line | cut -d\. -f1]
               send_user "$acctnum\n\r"
            }
         }
```

The output is:

```
2. word
2
```

"word" without the asterisks and "word" with an asterisk on either end does not work. I need this to be a variable which is provided on the command line. I have found no combination which will work with a variable.

Please provide suggestions to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in [Match a string with a substring in Expect scripting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/355618). I believe I had looked at that question before, but didn't read closely enough. The answer is to replace the curly braces with double quotes.

```
         foreach line [split $expect_out(buffer) \r\n] {
            if {[string match "*$varname*" $line]} {
               send_user "$line\r\n"
               set acctnum [exec echo $line | cut -d\. -f1]
               send_user "$acctnum\n\r"
            }
         }
```

Comment: Yes. Tcl uses braces as non-interpolating quotes, just like bash uses single quotes.

Comment: @glennjackman - Thanks for that tip.